# Unable to inject Web3 1.x version into Metamask

Tags: web3js, metamask

I am creating a dapp which interacts with Metamask on the browser. Metamask is injecting by default the 0.20.x version (deprecating soon) and I am trying to figure out how to inject 1.x version of web3 instead to Metamask. My code as follows:

Getting a minified version of web3 1.x version to include as script

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jslibs/web3.min.js"></script>
```

```
async initProvider() {
  if (ethereum) {
    this.web3Provider = ethereum;
    ethereum.enable();
    web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
    this.account = web3.eth.accounts[0];
    console.log(web3.version);
  } else {
    console.log("Please install Metamask to continue.");
  }
```

When I console.log the web3 version, it is still returning version 0.20.x to me. Any ideas why?